# Apache Ignite Affinity Collocation with Complex Join Conditions

Tags: sql, bigdata, ignite

I am using Ignite for a near real time application and I want to increase the performance of the queries I use. The query use SqlFieldsQuery and implies a complex join. for ex:

```
Select 
  col1 , col2 , col3 , col4 , .....
From 
  table1 A inner join table2 B
on 
  A.col5 = "subscribe" and A.col6="sell" and 
   ( 
     (A.col1 = B.col1 and B.col3="1")
     or (A.col2 = B.col1 and B.col3="2")
     or (A.col1 = B.col1 and B.col3="3")) .... etc.
```

1- The join here is not only using the same two columns to create affinity keys. What should I do? 
2- Other than this, what are the different recommendations to increase the performance of ignite queries (specifically queries)?

Comment: Could you please rephrase the first question? I'm not quite getting what's about.

Comment: I think the second question about general recommendations is not actually a StackOverflow format. You may try looking at https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging, but I'd suggest to remove that part from the question and maybe create separate, specific questions on Ignite SQL optimization if you have any.

Comment: Can you also rephrase number one? What's your current table structure? What's your affinity key?

Comment: @Stanislav Lukyanov
for Q1 ....
What I mean is that through out the examples I saw for the Affinity Keys, the were sth like a primary key foreign key relationship. for my query I have multiple columns included in the join. How should I implement the Affinity Keys in that case?

Comment: @alamar for Q1 .... What I mean is that through out the examples I saw for the Affinity Keys, they were sth like a primary key foreign key relationship. for my query I have multiple columns included in the join. How should I implement the Affinity Keys in that case?